# Reentrancy attack

Tags: solidity, security, reentrant-attacks

Can anyone explain this code to me

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ReEntrancyGuard{

    address[] public addr;
    bool locked;

    function addresslist(address Attacker) public{
        locked = false;

        msg.sender.call("");

        require(locked);
        addr.push(Attacker);
    }

    function lock() public{
        locked = true;
    }
}
```

Based on my understanding I wrote the following code

**Note: new to solidity and trying to develop logic here so forgive my syntactic errors**

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "./ReEntrancyGuard.sol";


contract Attack{
ReEntrancyGuard public targetContract;

constructor(address _targetContractAddress) {
    targetContract= ReEntrancyGuard(_targetContractAddress);
}

    fallback() external payable {
        if (targetContract).lock()= false){
         uint addr1.addresslist(msg.value);
       }
    }
     function attack() external payable{
         require(msg.sender);
         uint addr1 = targetContract.addresslist(msg.sender);
         addr1.addresslist(msg.value);

     }  
    

    
}
```

Comment: is this homework? it looks like homework since these contracts are pointless. What is the goal?

Comment: What do you not understand of the first contract? It has a private variable locked that can be modified by lock at any moment.